# Hibernate/Spring - JUnit fails with Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

We recently decided to change some methods from `@Transactional` to `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

and added `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>` in **applicationContext.xml**

**Everything works fine when running the application**, but our tests fails with the following exception:

```
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
insert 
into
    utfylling_versjon
    (opprettet, utfylling_id, id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?)

2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Mar 15 20:44:02 CET 2016]
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1216]
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1217]
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23506, SQLState: 23506
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_JA5LSNJNODJIEEC22M3HU3YIS: PUBLIC.UTFYLLING_VERSJON FOREIGN KEY(UTFYLLING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.UTFYLLING(ID) (1216)"; SQL statement:
insert into utfylling_versjon (opprettet, utfylling_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23506-191]
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-03-15 20:44:02 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@41289e88 testClass = RisikoServiceTest, testInstance = no.sb1.forsikring.seopp.kjerne.fip.RisikoServiceTest@7e8783b0, testMethod = sjekkAtFaktaBlirSatt@RisikoServiceTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK_JA5LSNJNODJIEEC22M3HU3YIS: PUBLIC.UTFYLLING_VERSJON FOREIGN KEY(UTFYLLING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.UTFYLLING(ID) (1216)"; SQL statement:
insert into utfylling_versjon (opprettet, utfylling_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23506-191]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@d0e4972 testClass = RisikoServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:test-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].

    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK_JA5LSNJNODJIEEC22M3HU3YIS: PUBLIC.UTFYLLING_VERSJON FOREIGN KEY(UTFYLLING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.UTFYLLING(ID) (1216)"; SQL statement:
    insert into utfylling_versjon (opprettet, utfylling_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23506-191]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
```

and more specific

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_JA5LSNJNODJIEEC22M3HU3YIS: PUBLIC.UTFYLLING_VERSJON FOREIGN KEY(UTFYLLING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.UTFYLLING(ID) (1216)"; SQL statement:
insert into utfylling_versjon (opprettet, utfylling_id, id) values (?, ?, ?) [23506-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
```

Why is it that it fails because we run a transaction with requires new?

If I change it back to `@Transactional` then everything works ok, but we want to run in a new transaction

EDIT:

Here is part of the code. I create Utfylling.

```
Utfylling utfylling = someService.createUtfylling();
//Perform some operations
someService.createUtfyllingVersjon(utfylling);

@Transactional
    public Utfylling createUtfylling() {
        Utfylling utfylling = new Utfylling()
        //some setters
        entityManager.persist(utfylling);
        return utfylling;
    }
```

Then I call create UtfyllingVersjon

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createUtfyllingVersjon(Utfylling utfylling) {
 UtfyllingVersjon utfyllingVersjon = new UtfyllingVersjon(utfylling);
            entityManager.persist(utfyllingVersjon);
//some more setters
utfylling.getUtfyllingVersjoner().add(utfyllingVersjon);
            entityManager.persist(utfyllingVersjon);
            entityManager.merge(utfylling);
}
```

Utfylling is detached when it comes inside createUtfyllingVersjon, so I have to use merge.
This works when running code locally in jetty, but when running JUnit test it fails.

Here is my test-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar"/>

    <bean id="dozerMapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper" />

    <bean id="h2DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="META-INF/persistence-test.xml"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="foo.bar" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="h2DataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="H2"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

    <bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="h2DataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I think this question cannot be answered from the details you provide because it's probably not the simply the change in propagation behavior that causes the problem, but also what you do in the existing transaction, what you do in the newly created one and how they relate to each other.

Comment: But why does it work on the same database when I run it locally compared to as a unit test?

Comment: Do you have a `@TransactionConfiguration` annotation on you JUnit class with the default attribute value for `defaultRollback = true`?

Comment: No and I don't believe we have any rollbacks on each test, because we are using H2 inmemory for all our tests with just create-drop

Comment: Are the junit tests themselves marked with `@Transactional`?

Comment: Yes they are. I can try removing it and check

Comment: That's the problem then. @Gab guessed it correctly in his answer.

Comment: Yes that was the problem indeed! Thank you. I will then mark Gabs answer as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess :

Spring `@Transactional` Default propagation level is REQUIERED, required spec is :"Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists."

The Unit test itself run in a transaction, the createUtfylling join the existing transaction then the createUtfyllingVersion suspend it, open it's own transaction which doesn't seen the pending change and trigger the foreign key exception.

During application runtime you have no enclosing transaction, the createUtfyllingVersion creates it's own new transaction commited immediatly (and so update is visible for following calls)

Comment: Thank you. I removed Transactional from the junit tests and it worked

Comment: Anyway the pb is not in your unit test but in your service layer design. You can't afford to let this code like that ; Either both call must be required or requires_new. It may be a service decomposition pb more than a transaction scope one.

Comment: I understand. I will look over the code and make sure each transaction is indeed separate, and don't share entites

Answer (score 2):

There are two different questions here:

**Why does it fail?**

This is fairly straightforward: in your code you are doing essentially two inserts. When you attempt to perform the second insert, you receive:

```
Referential integrity constraint violation
```

which is logical, since you just changed your code to execute the second insert in a separate transaction. **This new transaction does not "see" the record inserted by the previous one** (only committed, and in-transaction inserts would be visible in any given transaction), so the foreign-key constraint prevent you to insert the second row. Why? Because if the first transaction would be rollbacked for whatever reason, the second insert could lead to integrity-violation. So DB acts exactly as it should. In order to avoid this happening you need change your code in some way:

- either remove the FK constraint
- do not execute inserts that belong together in separate transactions (maybe just use REQUIRE, not REQUIRE_NEW)

**Why do you get different results from the test and from the main code?**

This is a bit harder. My only hypothesis is that your main code autocommits the first transaction, hence making the first insert visible for the second transaction. While your test keeps the first transaction hanging (probably to be rolled back in the end), and this way leads to the problem described above.

Comment: But we want to utfyllingversion to be stored in a separate transaction. How can I achieve this without getting the constraint? Removing the constraint is not an option :)